# How do I get the result of the database passed to my controller using Express, MySQL2 and TS

Tags: mysql, typescript, express

I have created a controller `blog.controller.ts` that looks like this:

```
export const getAllBlogs =  async(req: Request, res:Response) => {
    try {
        return findAllBlogs()
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500)
    } 
}
```

And a service `blog.service.ts` that looks like this:

```
export const findAllBlogs = async() => {
    dotenv.config()

    const db = await mysql.createConnection({
    user: process.env.USER,
    host: process.env.HOST,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB,
    })

    let result = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM blogs', (err, result) =>{
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }

        if(Array.isArray(result) && result.length != 0) {
            return result
        } else {
            return err
        }
    })

    return result
}
```

I want `let result` to have the value of the query.

I tried this and it gives the following:

```
{
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 0,
    "next": null,
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM blogs",
    "insertId": 0,
    "queryTimeout": null,
    "_rows": [],
    "_fields": [],
    "_result": [],
    "_fieldCount": 0,
    "_rowParser": null,
    "_executeOptions": {
        "sql": "SELECT * FROM blogs"
    },
    "_resultIndex": 0,
    "_localStream": null,
    "_connection": null
}
```

Now I wanted to only get the dataset, but in here it shows that my fields/rows are empty too.

I want it to show:

```
[
  {
    "id" = 1,
    "body" = "This is a body"
    "title" = "This is a title"
  }
]
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.6.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1"
  }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't `return` values from controllers, you send them to the response, eg `res.send(await findAllBlogs())`. You're also mixing promises with callbacks in `db.execute()`; don't do that

Comment: please add the `package.json` file content to your question first.

Comment: You're doing something quite weird with mixing callbacks and async/await. I wrote a post a while back as an intro to using mysql with node after seeing some odd things here. Hope it helps: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/